# Viscous approximation of Eikonal equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, viscosity-solutions

Consider the Eikonal equation
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}\left|D u\right|^{2}=1 & \text { on } \Omega \\ u \equiv 0 & \text { on } \partial \Omega\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and the viscous regularization
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}\varepsilon \Delta u_{\varepsilon}+\left|D u_{\varepsilon}\right|^{2}=1 & \text { on } \Omega \\ u_{\varepsilon} \equiv 0 & \text { on } \partial \Omega\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It is well-known that $u_\varepsilon$ converges uniformly to the unique viscosity solution $u$ of the Eikonal equation. Does the error estimate
$$\|u_\varepsilon - u\|_{\infty} \lesssim \sqrt{\varepsilon}$$
also holds?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a standard result. You can see sections 5.2 and 5.3 in these notes: [https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~jwcalder/viscosity_solutions.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ejwcalder/viscosity_solutions.pdf)

In fact, the rate is $O(\varepsilon)$ in one direction, when the boundary is $C^2$, since in this case $u$ is semiconcave.

Comment: In your notes, a lot of heavy lifting is one by the fact that the equation is of the form $u+H(x,\nabla u) = 0$, i.e. there's a zero-order term appearing with the right sign. Is it actually possible to prove the same result for $H(x,\nabla u)=0$?

Comment: Yes, have a look at Theorem 9.17 in my notes. This is for monotone finite difference schemes, but the proof is very similar to that of viscous approximations and this is for $H(x,\nabla u)=0$. You need some additional structure conditions on $H$ in this case to allow perturbation to strict sub/super solutions.

Comment: The eikonal equations satisfies the structure condition I mentioned.